# List content type causing workflow issue

Tags: list, workflow, content-type

I stupidly changed the content site content type for a list last week and now none of my workflows work, I cannot remember what it was called before I renamed it 'Goal'.(At least this is what I am putting it down to)

In the workflows if I approve the item it still appears as pending.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance?

[image]